# Ловушка для ошибок

Tags: delphi, исключения

Доброго времени суток! Пишу программу для передачи файлов по сети (протокол TCP), используя компоненты `Indy idTCPServer`, `idTCPClient`. На стороне клиента пишу следущий код для приема файла от сервера:

```
try
   put:=directorylistbox1.Directory+'\';
   IdTCPClient1.ConnectAndGetAll;
except
   // **Обработка исключений.**..
end;
```

Вопрос такой, как можно подключить конструкцию `try..except` чтобы она различала различные ошибки при получение данных:

1. Сервер не отвечает
2. Размер файла велик слишком
3. Файл на сервере отсутствует
4. Разрыв соединения до окончания получения файла?

Подскажите, что нужно прописать в обработке исключений?

Answer (score 1):

См. справку

```
try
 ...
except
  on E:EZeroDivide do HandleZeroDivide(E);
  on E:EOverflow do HandleOverflow(E);
  on E:EMathError do HandleMathError(E);
end;
```

В соответствующем исключении для indy должен быть код ошибки.

**UPD** добавил в код описание переменной исключения, которая будет содержать информацию об исключении (E.message и т.д.).

Comment: EZeroDivide, EOverflow, EMathError откуда взяты, что именно они обрабатывают? Где можно увидеть список возможных исключений для моего случая?

Comment: Есть файл IdException.pas, в котором описаны все возможные исключения. В справке по indy о них есть краткая информация. Их много, да. Естественно не все они могут возникнуть, поэтому можно в коде посмотреть по конкретному методу, в справке тоже пишут про некоторые исключения.  
Кстати говоря не все ваши ситуации могут вызывать исключения, универсального метода все равно нет - какие ситуации вам надо обрабатывать, соответственно их надо и диагностировать, остальные исключения перекрывайте через базовый класс Exception, логируйте.